# Auto - updated change date in Powerpoint

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, date

Is there a way to add date of the last slide change to powerpoint?

The date as offered by powerpoint can be fixed or auto-updated, but this updates at each printig/opening. I would like it to update when the slide changes, not when it is only viewed/printed.

Answer (score 0):

#### Is there a way to add date of the last slide change to PowerPoint?

You can use a macro triggered by a button, as follows:

```
Sub UpdateModifyDateOnMaster()
Dim oShp As Shape
For i = 1 To ActivePresentation.Designs.Count
    With ActivePresentation.Designs(i).SlideMaster.Shapes
        For j = 1 To .Placeholders.Count
            If .Placeholders(j).PlaceholderFormat.Type = ppPlaceholderDate Then
                .Placeholders(j).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Last Modified: " & Format(Now(), "mm/dd/yyyy")
            End If
        Next
    End With
Next
End Sub

Sub UpdateModifyDateOnSlides()
Dim oShp As Shape
For i = 1 To ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Count
    With ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange(i).Shapes
        For j = 1 To .Count
            If .Item(j).Type = msoPlaceholder Then
                If .Item(j).PlaceholderFormat.Type = ppPlaceholderDate Then
                    .Item(j).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Last Modified: " & Format(Now(), "mm/dd/yyyy")
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End With
Next
End Sub
```

> - Assign a button to fire this when you want to update the modified date. - You can use either of the two.
> - The first macro checks for the date placeholder on the slide master and updates it.
> - The second macro checks for date placeholder on the selected range of slides and updates it.

Source [Insert last modified date in PowerPoint](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-powerpoint/insert-last-modified-date-in-powerpoint/b5342295-e477-4652-bd1b-771119b9fd77?auth=1)